# Multiple library dependencies in Android and Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I've created an augmented reality app using Unity and Vuforia. I've also created a normal Android app using Actionbar sherlock. Everything is fine, until I had to combine the two projects. I use actionbar sherlock as an Android library, the same for the Unity part. But when I reference both projects my Unity part can't be resolved?

I'm developing in Eclipse. leave a comment if you need some extra info on my setup.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm so sorry for being a noob! The problem was actually written in the Console! If I just read there before posting!

OK the problem was simple, I referred to the android-supprt-v4.jar both in the actionbar sherloc and my main project. After removing android-supprt-v4.jar from my main projects lib folder, everything works as a charm.